# Passing in form data doesn't give response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

I am running a basic web application which is going to do simple queries against a mongoDb via mongoose in node.js running express.  If I do a simple find(), i can return the entire dataset, however, when I try to pass in form data as a variable to find a specific restaurant ie find({restaurantname: Arbys}), I can't get a response.  I am using handlebars for passing variables back to the client.  It seems as though it is a routing issue but I may me misunderstanding how to handle GET/POST

This is the js which does the querying

```
//external packages
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var csrf = require('csurf');
var passport = require('passport');

//organic packages & models
var restData = require('../models/restaurants');



/* GET Mongo home page. */
router.get('./mongo', function(req,res,next){
    res.render('mongo');
});

//Get Data  **This works fine**
router.get('/get-data', function(req,res,next){
    restData.find()
        .then(function(doc){
            res.render('mongo/mongo', {items: doc});
        })
});

//Goes to query page with form input 
router.get('/query-data', function(req,res,next){
   res.render('mongo/mongo-query');
});

//Query specific data **This does not work**
router.get('/query-data-details', function(req,res,next){
    var RestaurantName = req.query['RestaurantName'];
    if (RestaurantName.length == 0) {
        res.render('mongo/mongo', {items: "No Docs Found"});
    } else {
        restData.find({name: RestaurantName})
            .then(function (doc) {
                res.render('mongo/mongo', {items: doc});
                console.log(RestaurantName);
            });
    }
});
```

This is the handlebars script which successfully returns the find() with no query parameters

```
<div class="container float-left">
        <a href="/mongo/get-data" <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Load All Data</button></a>
        <a href="/mongo/query-data" <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Query Specific Data</button></a>
        <h2>Data</h2>
        <p>Retrieves restauraunt data by Name, Cuisine, Borough and Address
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Cuisine</th>
                    <th>Borough</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {{# each items }}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{this.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{this.cuisine}}</td>
                    <td>{{this.borough}}</td>
                    <td>{{this.address}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

and finally, this is what I have thus far for trying to query a specific restaurant name

```
<form method="get" action="/query-data-details">
    <input type=text name="RestaurantName">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

app.js portion

```
var routeshome = require('./routes/index');
var routesmongo = require('./routes/mongo');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

require('./config/passport');

// view engine setup
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layousDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts' }));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({secret: 'b5Frapradra5wen', saveUninitialized: false, resave: false}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routeshome);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/mongo', routesmongo);
```

Comment: By "can't get a response" do you mean you never get back an HTTP response?

Comment: more specifically,  I get a "Not Found" at this URL http://localhost:3000/query-data-details?RestaurantName=Test

Comment: Try changing the following: var RestaurantName = req.body.RestaurantName;

Answer (score -2):

It seems you are sending RestaurantName in url params ...

try changing your route from 
"/query-data-details" to 
"/query-data-details/:RestaurantName" 
then you can get RestaurantName 
var RestaurantName = req.query['RestaurantName'];

Comment: No luck but I think I may have an issue with my mapping in my app.js file, I a added the relevant parts of the app file up top.  I think i need to route through there to my mongo.js file?